# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-2.x, splinter

I have the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import splinter
import urllib

browser = splinter.Browser('firefox')

miss = ("rúin",)

for i in miss:
    browser.visit(link)
    browser.fill('word', i)
```

Which gives me the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use an actual unicode value:

```
miss = (u"rúin",)
```

Note the `u` before the string literal.

Python otherwise will try to coerce the bytestring to unicode implicitly, using the default codec (ASCII).